# return Stream values from a source of data in java function

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, java-stream

Suppose data are written in Kafka. I want to write a function to return a `Stream` of unbounded values in Kafka. The following is the template of my function:

```
public static Stream<Byte[]> getData(String topic, int from){
        // some kafka configurations
        consumer.subscribe(topic, listener);
        ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records;
        Stream<Byte[]> res ;
        while (true){
            records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
                res.add(record);
            }
        return res;
        }
}
```

I know somewhere is syntactically wrong, but this is what I need to. For example in the `main` function someone gets the value of `getData` function:

```
Stream<Byte[]> results = getData("topic", 0);
```

and data are pushing to `results` variable again and again, as a stream.
How can I do that, is it possible?

Comment: You have an infinite loop, so your method will never return. Generally, this kind of stream is not suitable for this kind of task. You may look for [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/)…

Comment: @Holger I agree that Reactive Streams or Project Reactor or even RxJava are better fits for OP's use case. However, couldn't you just use the `consumer.poll(100)` operation as the source of an infinite stream with `Stream.generate` and then return the stream instance?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner you could, but would have to live with the fact that most stream operations do not work as intended then. Think of any terminal operation other than `forEach` or what would happen when turning the stream to parallel. While infinite streams were considered in the design, they are not meant to do continuously polling.